# Multiple dropdown menus in rails 6

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, memory-efficient

Quite new to rails and can't figure out how to build a dynamic menu bar.
The database uses a simple method to store menu items:

```
id | title   | url             | parent | position
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Books     /books            0        1 (first link on menu bar)
2    Fiction   /books/fiction    1        1 (first link under Books menu)
3    CDs       /cd               0        2 (second link on menu bar)
4    Fantasy   /books/fantasy    1
5    Singles   /cd/single        2
6    Albums    /cd/album         2
```

I need to get all entries in this table and display them according to their parent.
All the items with parent 0 will show on the menu bar.
When user hovers any parent, all its child elements are listed below it.

When I did this in PHP, I used a loop that resulted in many database calls; One to get all the parent items in position order (as the admin can change the order in which the parent items appear on the menu), and then one for each parent to get all its child elements (also in position order).
I then added each resulting item to an array that was named after the parent_id and finally concatonated the arrays.

$item[$parent][] = '<a href...'

I know the SQL was inefficient (and the PHP probably was, too) but it didn't matter back then. Now it does.

Any idea how I can make this work efficiently in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the database table that stores this menu information is called nav_items. Then the Rails convention would be to have a model called NavItem:

```rb
# app/models/nav_item.rb
class NavItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :child_menu_items, class_name: NavItem, inverse_of: :parent_menu_item, foreign_key: :parent
  belongs_to :parent_menu_item, class_name: NavItem, foreign_key: :parent, inverse_of: :child_menu_items

  scope :top_level, { where("parent = ?", 0) }
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :populate_nav_vars

  private
  def populate_nav_vars
    @nav_items = NavItem.top_level
  end
end

# app/view/layouts/_nav.html
# @nav_items is defined in the controller as NavItem.top_level
# the nav structure is shown here as nested <ul> lists
# it can be rendered appropriately with css (e.g. Bootstrap)
<ul>
<%- @nav_items.each do |top_level_item| %>
   <li><%= top_level_item.title %></li>
   <li>
     <ul>
       <%- top_level_item.child_menu_items.each do |child_item| %>
         <li><%= child_item.title %>
       <%- end %>
     </ul>
   </li>
<%- end %>
</ul>
```

You really shouldn't worry about performance, it should not be noticeable at all. I assume here that you want the navigation menu on every page, so the convenient place to populate the required variables is in `ApplicationController` and populate the variable in a before_action callback.

If the performance issue concerns you, then you should make the navigation page elements a view partial, and apply rails caching to the partial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This line confuses me:
@nav_items is defined in the controller as NavItem.top_level
Is it a private function? How do I define this so it will still be available to the view which is rendered on every page load?

I also have this error at the moment:
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting => ...vel, { where("parent = ?", 0) }

Comment: Sorry, I was being lazy! I've updated my answer to show how to populate the @nav_items variable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. It is working now in terms of not throwing erros, but the behavior isn't as expected. The child_item.title line is outputting the same link as the top_level_item.title, so I'm getting all the links twice. I've tried to figure out what's going on but I can't. Is there some additional definition required somewhere, perhaps in the scope definition inside the model class? It seems somehow incomplete but it's beyond me exactly why. Also, is there a special meaning for <%- ? It seems to have the same effect as <% (without the hyphen).

Comment: OK, you need to debug from the Rails console. Get the first top level menu item and inspect it to confirm it's what you expect `> item = NavItem.top_level.first` then `> item.title` should be "Books". Then get the first child NavItem `> c= item.child_menu_items.first` and inspect with `c.title` should be 'Fiction', and similarly inspect the second child item, Please report what you find. On the erb question, there's little difference between `<%-` and `<%`, I just don't write much erb and I added the `-` inadvertently.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include `inverse_of` on the associations, I think it's necessary here.

Comment: The first item is fine. It outputs the full first line from the nav_items table as expected. Strangely, the sql created by the second item is not as expected. c = item.child_menu_items.first ::  "SELECT `nav_items`.* FROM `nav_items` WHERE `nav_items`.`nav_item_id` = 1..."

Comment: try with the `inverse_of` parameter for the associations (see edited answer)

Comment: The `inverse_of` parameters are added and the result is as in my previous reply. Is there another way to achieve this or is this the best option? I'm not sure why it doesn't want to work.

Comment: Try adding `foreign_key: :parent` to the has_many association, I'll update the anwer

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Seems to be working perfectly now. Still a lot for me to learn about rails but I really appreaciate your continuing to try to help me through this one. :)